# Domain co-domain, proof check

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, definition

> Let $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R},g:B\rightarrow\mathbb{R},g \circ f:C\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
>
> Then we have:
>
> 1.$C\subseteq A$
>
> 2.$f(C)\subseteq B$

Proof.

$\forall c \in C,g \circ f$ is defined on c

$\Rightarrow f$ is defined on c that $ c \in A$

and $g$ is defined on $f(c)$ that$ f(c)\in B$

$\Rightarrow \forall c \in C,c \in A$ and $f(c)\in B$

$\Rightarrow C\subseteq A$ and $f(C)\subseteq B$

---

Questions:

1.Are these statements true?

2.Does my proof look fine?

3.Is there any other nice relationship between

domain,codomain and range

***with condition $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R},g:B\rightarrow\mathbb{R},g \circ f:C\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$***?

Thanks :)

---

**Definitions I'm using:**

***$f:A\rightarrow{B}$:***

$f$:domain $\rightarrow$ co-domain

***domain:***

Subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that $f$ is defined on

(for example, domain of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$)

***co-domain:***

$\mathbb{R}$ as default

***range:***

Outputs of $f$ as a subset in co-domain